# Rail Admin - Bootstrap datepicker don't appear

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rails-admin

everybody.

I'm using Rails admin and in date fields the bootstap datepicker widget don't appears when input is active. The element is added in html, but style stay as `display: none`.

The only error that appears in Web Dev Console is this (I really do not think this has anything to do with datepicker):

[image]
[image]

[image]

How can I correct that? I'm using a another datepicker in my site in another page. Can this be conflicting?

Thanks!

Comment: see the console what is the error?

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatinI updated the question with web console errors. Nothing appears in the application log.

Comment: JavaScript errors will usually prevent other JS code to execute so that error is probably preventing the code that displays the datepicker to be executed. Find whatever is throwing that error and fix it, once you have no errors your datepicker should display fine, if it still doesn't, then update your question with proper information like the actual code that you wrote and we might be able to help you.

Comment: @Julien I figured out what it happened. It was just a conflict with another jQuery plugin that I was using in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what it happened. It was just a conflict with another jQuery plugin that I was using in my application.

I was using a jQuery plugin to upload file via Ajax. I stopped using it (the plugin it was not so important) that and everything works fine now.